# Google Fonts Roboto not rendering the various font weights in Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, fonts

I am having a issue rendering the Google Fonts hosted Roboto weights in Google Chrome specificlly, it works well in Firefox and other major browser. I have triple checked the implementation which is correct and implemented other fonts with various weights to test(which works) and the various implementation methods Google fonts offer.

Further analysis at the network request shows a response with the various font-faces linked to the external fonts however not all of them download specifically light.

I should note a couple of days ago all was working fine, im wondering is anybody recently is experiencing this problem?

Comment: Does Google return the same font CSS for Firefox and Chrome?

Comment: for the initial request yes which is the various font-faces however google chrome then doesn't follow all the links in the font-face url. home that makes sense